# copying files into Xcode

Tags: xcode

I have a project with quite a few png files.  I'm not sure how it happens, but every once in a while, the "copy items to destination group folder(if needed)" checkbox becomes unchecked, and I will add quite a few files without realizing they aren't being copied.  I was wondering if there was a way within Xcode to copy those files into the project.  I don't want to re-add them all, because there are tons of them. I'd prefer if I could just mass select the files in that left panel within Xcode and press a button, and have it be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's a better option, but you can always edit the pxbproj file in a text editor (right click the xcodeproj file, show package contents to find it).

Look for values like this:

```
path = "../../../Desktop/Foobar.png";
```

And change to:

```
path = "Artwork/foobar.png"
```

Do this while Xcode is closed (or at least the project is closed) and make sure you commit the entire project to git before making any edits, so you can roll back if something goes wrong.

Comment: I found a way to do it.  i just mass select the files, then i press "show in finder".  From there they are already selected, so i Just pull them back in the project and copy them this time.  Then I mass delete the references that were  there before.  Thanks for your answer though